# Python, stopping windows service (Unbind from socket)

Tags: python, windows, service, syslog

I have a simple Syslog Receiver that starts as windows service. The Service starts just fine... however I can't get it to stop when I hit "stop service". I'm sure it's because I'm bound to a socket. However, I can't figure out how to un-bind to a socket from the SvcStop Function. Anyone have any ideas?

```
OUTPUT_LOG_FILE = 'C:\temp\output.log'
HOST = "192.168.X.X"
PORT = 514
import SocketServer
import pythoncom
import win32serviceutil
import win32service
import win32event
import servicemanager
import socket

class AppServerSvc (win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework):
    _svc_name_ = "Simple Syslog Receiver"
    _svc_display_name_ = "Simple Syslog Receiver"
    server = ""

    def __init__(self, args):
        win32serviceutil.ServiceFramework.__init__(self, args)
        self.hWaitStop = win32event.CreateEvent(None, 0, 0, None)
        socket.setdefaulttimeout(60)

    def SvcStop(self):
        self.ReportServiceStatus(win32service.SERVICE_STOP_PENDING)
        win32event.SetEvent(self.hWaitStop)

    def SvcDoRun(self):
        servicemanager.LogMsg(servicemanager.EVENTLOG_INFORMATION_TYPE,
                              servicemanager.PYS_SERVICE_STARTED,
                              (self._svc_name_,''))
        self.main()

    def main(self):
        try:
            global server
            server = SocketServer.UDPServer((HOST, PORT), SyslogUDPHandler)
            server.serve_forever(poll_interval=0.5)
        except (IOError, SystemExit):
            raise
        pass



class SyslogUDPHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):
        data = bytes.decode(self.request[0].strip())

        with open(OUTPUT_LOG_FILE, 'w+') as outputfile:
            outputfile.write(str(data))
        outputfile.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    win32serviceutil.HandleCommandLine(AppServerSvc)
```

Comment: When you stop the service you have to call the server's [`shutdown`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socketserver.html#SocketServer.BaseServer.shutdown) method.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem on Windows 7 + VirtualBox.

The only solution I have is to remove this particular port from being forwarded in VirtualBox, or use a new port.

Even the standard socket server code from basic example has this feature:
 1. It runs forever
 2. You can not see it in the windows processes 
 3. It is not "because It bounded to a socket" as it continues to replay properly, although Python application is closed.

```
    import socket

    TCP_IP = '127.0.0.1'
    TCP_PORT = 80
    BUFFER_SIZE = 20 

    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    s.bind((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.listen(1)

    conn, addr = s.accept()
    print 'Connection address:', addr
    while 1:
        data = conn.recv(BUFFER_SIZE)
        if not data: break
        print "received data:", data
        conn.send(data)  # echo

    conn.close()
    s.close()
    raw_input()
```